# jedis - Can't connect to redis after JMS request - access denied

Tags: java, redis, jms, jedis, mbeans

The language I'm using is Java (Groovy).

I'm using javax.JMS to send a file over a JMS WebLogic queue. Immediately after successfully sending the JMS message (separately verified), I call close() methods from my QueueSession instance and then from my QueueConnection instance.

After all this, I try to connect to redis using jedis (which works perfectly in every other context) and I immediately get this error message:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "register")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:585)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrustPermission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1848)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:322)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.jmxRegister(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:883)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.<init>(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:130)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.<init>(GenericObjectPool.java:107)
at redis.clients.util.Pool.initPool(Pool.java:44)
at redis.clients.util.Pool.<init>(Pool.java:23)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:185)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:162)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:28)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor46.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:255)
at com.<mysoftware>.core.Ecosystem.createRedisConnection(Ecosystem.groovy:93)
```

which is when I call new JedisPool(...) - Again, I never have issues with JedisPool. **I only have this issue after sending a file over the JMS queue.**

How can I solve this issue? I've seen that someone on SO suggests adding a line to java.policy file, but can I do this in my program? I don't want to add new very specific steps to my software's installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the port number JMS is using, the port number used by jms could be blocked on redis. If you are using unix based machine then you can simply check it by using telnet command. eg:

```
telnet RedisInstance Portnumber
```

Comment: Sadly, it's not a port conflict. They're using two different ports.